# Can I Set Diaper SizeLevelNumber & BrandLevelNumber using an array or different Method?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, optimization

Here's a small program to tell our employee's the price of our diapers. Is there a way such as an int array or an optimized way to set brandLevelNumber & sizeLevelNumber to the selected items in the brandComboBox & the sizeComboBox?

Also, do you guys think there's a better way for the method calculatePricePerDiaper() to work than a switch within a switch, or any other suggestions at all?

```
class Diaper
{
    public string brandLevel;
    public string sizeLevel;
    public int brandLevelNumber;
    public int sizeLevelNumber;

    public string[] brands = {"Earth's Best", "Huggies Snug & Dry", "Huggies Snugglers & Movers",
                        "Luvs", "Pampers Baby Dry", "Pampers Swaddlers & Cruisers", "Seventh Generation",
                        "Store"};
    public string[] size = {"Size 1", "Size 2", "Size 3", "Size 4", "Size 5", "Size 6 & 7",
                             "Size N","2T-3T", "3T-4T", "4T-5T","Big Kids" };
    public double count;
    public double price;
    private double pricePerDiaper;
    public double finalPrice;


    public double calculatePricePerDiaper()
    {

            switch (brandLevelNumber)
            {
                case 0:
                    switch (sizeLevelNumber)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            if (count > 0 && count < 50)
                                pricePerDiaper = 0.12;
                            if (count > 50 && count <= 160)
                                pricePerDiaper = 0.11;
                            if (count > 160)
                                pricePerDiaper = 0.10;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (count > 0 && count <= 42)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.13;
                            if (count > 42 && count <=105)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.12;
                            if (count > 150)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.11;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                             if (count > 0 && count <=36)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.16;
                            if (count >36)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.12;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            if (count > 0 && count <=31)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.18;
                            if (count > 31 && count <=85)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.15;
                            if (count >85)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.14;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            if (count > 0 && count <=28)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.21;
                            if (count > 28 && count <= 100)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.17;
                            if (count > 100)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.16;
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            if (count > 0 && count <=25)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.24;
                            if (count > 25)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.20;
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            if (count > 0 && count <=50)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.12;
                            if (count > 50)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.11;
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            if (count > 0 && count <=30)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.23;
                            if (count >30 && count <= 160)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.22;
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            if (count > 0 && count <=25)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.26;
                            if (count > 25 && count <= 55)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.25;
                            if (count > 61)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.24;
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            if (count > 0 && count <=22)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.32;
                            if (count > 22 && count <= 40)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.31;
                            if (count > 40 && count <= 60)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.29;
                            if (count>60)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.27;
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            if (count > 0 && count <=20)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.41;
                            if (count > 20 && count <= 37)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.37;
                            if (count >37)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.36;
                            break;
                    }
                break;
            }

        return pricePerDiaper;
    }
    public double calculatePrice(double pricePerDiaper, double count)
    {
        price = pricePerDiaper * count;
        return price;
    }

}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Diaper item = new Diaper();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        brandComboBox.DataSource = item.brands;
        sizeComboBox.DataSource = item.size;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Make the comboboxes appear empty at initial load
        //brandComboBox.SelectedItem = null;
        //sizeComboBox.SelectedItem = null;
    }

    private void countTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //So exception isn't thrown if user deletes countTextBox.Text
        string i = countTextBox.Text;
        if (double.TryParse(i, out item.count))
            item.count = Convert.ToDouble(countTextBox.Text);
    }

    private void doneButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        item.finalPrice=(item.calculatePrice(item.calculatePricePerDiaper(), Convert.ToDouble(countTextBox.Text)));
        priceLabel.Text = "$" + item.finalPrice;
    }

    private void brandComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        item.brandLevel = (string)brandComboBox.SelectedItem;
        switch (item.brandLevel)
        {
            case "Huggies Snug & Dry":
            case "Pampers Baby Dry":
                item.brandLevelNumber = 0;
                break;
            case "Earth's Best":
            case "Huggies Snugglers & Movers":
            case "Pampers Swaddlers & Cruisers":
            case "Seventh Generation":
                item.brandLevelNumber = 1;
                break;
            case "Luvs":
                item.brandLevelNumber = 2;
                break;
            case "Store":
                item.brandLevelNumber = 3;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void sizeComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        item.sizeLevel = (string)sizeComboBox.SelectedItem;
        switch (item.sizeLevel)
        {
            case "Size 1":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 1;
                break;
            case "Size 2":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 2;
                break;
            case "Size 3":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 3;
                break;
            case "Size 4":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 4;
                break;
            case "Size 5":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 5;
                break;
            case "Size 6 & 7":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 6;
                break;
            case "Size N":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 7;
                break;
            case "2T-3T":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 8;
                break;
            case "3T-4T":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 9;
                break;
            case "4T-5T":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 10;
                break;
            case "Big Kids":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 11;
                break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you are looking for an "optimized way", I assume this code is working. If that's the case, this question belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using arrays of classes to store your info.

```
class DiaperBrandClass {   
    public string BrandName;
    public int BrandLevelNumber;

    public DiaperBrandClass(string brandName, int brandLevel)
    {
        this.BrandName = brandName;
        this.BrandLevelNumber = brandLevel;
    }
}

class DiaperSizeClass {
    public int SizeLevelNumber;
    public string SizeDescription;      // This could be made an enum
    public float BasePrice;
    public Dictionary<int, float> Discounts;

    public DiaperSizeClass(int sizeLevel, float basePrice, Dictionary<int, float> discounts, string description)
    {
        this.SizeLevelNumber = sizeLevel;
        this.BasePrice = basePrice;
        this.Discounts = discounts;
        this.SizeDescription = description;
    }
}

class DiaperBrandLevelClass {
    public DiaperSizeClass[] DiaperSizes;

    public DiaperBrandLevelClass(DiaperSizeClass[] diaperSizes)
    {
        this.DiaperSizes = diaperSizes;
    }
}
```

Then you can define each diaper either at design time or runtime. Example at design time:

```
// We have 4 brand levels
DiaperBrandLevelClass[] DiaperBrandLevels = new DiaperBrandLevelClass[4];

// We would create the 10 DiaperSizeLevels for EACH of the 4 DiaperBrandLevels
DiaperSizeClass[] DiaperSizeLevels = new DiaperSizeClass[10];
// Brand Level #0 (the 'Drys')
DiaperBrandLevels[0] = new DiaperBrandLevelClass(DiaperSizeLevels);

// DiaperBrandLevels[0] - Size level #0 ("Size 1")
DiaperSizeLevels[0] = new DiaperSizeClass(
    0,
    0.12f, 
    new Dictionary<int, float>()
    {
        {50, 0.01},      // Anything above 50 gets a 0.01 discount
        {160, 0.02}      // Anything above 160 gets a 0.02 discount
    },
    "Size 1"
);
// Size level #1 ("Size 2")
DiaperSizeLevels[1] = new DiaperSizeClass(
    1,
    0.13f, 
    new Dictionary<int, float>()
    {
        {42, 0.01},      // Anything above 50 gets a 0.01 discount
        {105, 0.02}      // Anything above 160 gets a 0.02 discount
    },
    "Size 2"
);
// ... for Size Levels #2-9 ...

// ... repeat the same as above for the other BrandLevels ...
```

You would also create each brand:

```
DiaperBrandClass[] DiaperBrands = new DiaperBrandClass[8];
DiaperBrands[0] = new DiaperBrandClass("Earth's Best", 1);
DiaperBrands[1] = new DiaperBrandClass("Huggies Snug & Dry", 0);
// ...
```

You can then use:

```
int SelectedBrandLevel = DiaperBrands[brandComboBox.Index].BrandLevelNumber;
float BasePrice = DiaperBrandLevels[SelectedBrandLevel].DiaperSizes[sizeComboBox.Index].BasePrice;    float Discount = DiaperBrandLevels[SelectedBrandLevel].DiaperSizes[sizeComboBox.Index].Discounts[NumberOfDiapers];
```

Of course no error checking has been included and this was written with no compiler or IDE nearby so there may be mistakes, but the basic idea is there. The bonus to this method is that you could create a text/xml file that holds all the brands, prices, levels, etc that the program could load so you wouldn't need to recompile the code every time a price changed. Hard coding stuff like that needs to be avoided (but is fine for test purposes).

EDIT:
Recommend that if you use text files have a comment character such as #.

A brand file  could be as simple as each line containing the name and brand level, such as:

```
# List all brands using "<name>", <brand level>
"Earth's Best", 1
"Huggies Snug & Dry", 0
```

Then you could create brand level files   which would hold the pricing of each level (possibly in 2 lines, the file setup is your choice):

```
# List each size as <size level>, <base price>, "<description>" on first line
# and (<threshold1>, <discount1>), (<threshold2>, <discount2>), etc on second
0, 0.12f, "Size 1"
(50, 0.01), (160, 0.02)
1, 0.13f, "Size 2"
(42, 0.01), (105, 0.02)
```

Something like this. How you layout the files is your choice, just a basic idea for you. You can also google XML files and C# code to read/write XML files.

Comment: I would click the up arrow, but unfortunately my reputation is too low for it to count. I really appreciate your feedback. I also really like your idea for maintainability for when I'm not working here, then the R&D person can edit the text/xml file. I was thinking I would have to set up a whole different form in the Winform with functions to add brand levels, update prices, etc. I'm not sure how to "create a text/xml file that holds all the brands, prices, levels, etc that the program could load" though. If you have time and are willing,could you possibly e-mail me at Tyler@sommersmarket.com?

Comment: You could create multiple text files. See examples in edit above.

Comment: Okay great. Thank you for your insight. I also have other pricing programs to write, and this is a much bigger project than just diapers. So far I wrote a pet prices one which used something similar to the switches methodology. I can edit that one and the diaper one, and then I'll probably move onto toilet paper, napkins, and some other categories we have streamlined for pricing.

Comment: You may want to look into making it expandable to all departments/products. XML would definitely be an asset. Start with a file to store all the department names with a unique ID and/or filename that can be used to locate the file for that department. Each department would have it's own list of products each with a unique ID and/or filename again to reference that department's products. Then each product file would store it's own information. XML would allow easier sectioning within the files (such as Brand Levels, Brands, Pricing, etc).